# wp_mail sending old content from post

Tags: wp-mail, post-content

I have a function that sends out emails using `wp_mail()` every time a post is published or updated. However, the content that is being sent is always one post behind.

If I update the content the email sends the previous content before the update. I am not sure how to fix. I appreciate any help you can give, thanks.

```
function send_media_emails($post_id){
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) 
        return;
    if(get_post_status($post_id) == 'draft' or get_post_status($post_id) == 'pending' or get_post_status($post_id) == 'trash')
        return;
    $to  = 'email@email.com';
    $subject = 'My Email Subject';
    $post = get_post();

    $body = '<h1>'.$post->post_title.'</h1>';   
    if(is_category){
        $category = get_the_category();
        $body .= '<h2>Reason for Closure: <em>'.$category[0]->cat_name .'</em></h2>';
    }
    $body .= '<h3>This Cancellation/Delay was posted on '.$post->post_date.'</h3>';
    $body .= '<p>'.$post->post_content.'</p>';
    $body .= '<p>View this posting at ' . get_permalink($post_id) . ' or</p>';

    if(did_action('post_updated') == 1){
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $body);
    }
}
add_action('post_updated', 'send_media_emails');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few things you need to do here, you need to modify your `add_action()` to accept additional arguments and you need to specify whether to use the data *before* the update or the data *after* the update.

Try something like this:

```
function send_media_emails($post_id, $post_after){
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) 
        return;
    if(get_post_status($post_id) == 'draft' or get_post_status($post_id) == 'pending' or get_post_status($post_id) == 'trash')
        return;
    $to  = 'email@email.com';
    $subject = 'My Email Subject';
    $post = $post_after; // NOTE We're using the after post update data here

    $body = '<h1>'.$post->post_title.'</h1>';   
    if(is_category){
        $category = get_the_category();
        $body .= '<h2>Reason for Closure: <em>'.$category[0]->cat_name .'</em></h2>';
    }
    $body .= '<h3>This Cancellation/Delay was posted on '.$post->post_date.'</h3>';
    $body .= '<p>'.$post->post_content.'</p>';
    $body .= '<p>View this posting at ' . get_permalink($post_id) . ' or</p>';

    if(did_action('post_updated') == 1){
        wp_mail($to, $subject, $body);
    }
}
add_action('post_updated', 'send_media_emails', 10, 2); 
// NOTE we've added 2 arguments to be accepted and also a priority of 10
```

More information on the `add_action()` arguments can be [found here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action) and you can see an example of the before and after post data on the `post_updated` action [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/post_updated#example)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Craig, It worked like a charm. I  am a little foggy on one thing though. Where are my post variable being set if not in $post = get_post(); that is now $post = $post_after as I use the $post variable to grab all the content. Sorry if that is a dumb question.

Comment: No it's not a dumb question, this is set in the "function" `post_updated` all we're doing when using `add_action` is saying "Hey, I want to hook into an existing function and I want access to all the variables in that function". And if you were to find `post_updated` in the wordpress core you'd see that it stores data in the variables: `$post_id`, `$post_after` and `$post_before`. In this case this function is found in `wp-includes\post.php` - Which you should never modify because it's a core file

Comment: Makes sense, Thanks for explaining and helping me out, greatly appreciated.

Comment: To clarify: `post_updated` sets `$post_after` like so within the WordPress core: `$post_after = get_post($post_id);`

Comment: I just noticed that after I used the post_after, my $post->post_title no longer appears unless I update the post. I tried adding the post_before thinking it would return but no luck.

Comment: Ahhh okay sorry about that maybe on line 7 you could use `$post = get_post($post_id);`

Comment: That didn't seem to work either, but I figured it out. I pull my title from a custom taxonomy. The title comes from a selected term inside it. I had to place the term name to be the title and then it works. $terms =   wp_get_post_terms($post_id, 'regions');
 $title = $title ? $title : $terms[0]->name; Thanks for all your help again